Parameterization of Kasner exponents
The Kasner metric is given by,
\begin{equation} \tag{1} \label{1}
ds^2 = -dt^2 + t^{2 p_1} dx^2 + t^{2 p_2} dy^2 + t^{2 p_3} dz^2
\end{equation}
where $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are the Kasner exponents. Einstein's equation for empty space is given by,
\begin{equation} \tag{2} \label{2}
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu} = 0
\end{equation}
This leads to a vanishing Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ and Ricci scalar $R = 0$. For the metric eq.(\ref{1}) to be a solution of eq.(\ref{2}), we can solve for $R_{\mu\nu}$ using eq.(\ref{1}), and then imposing $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$. This will lead to two constraints,
\begin{align} \tag{3} \label{3}
& p_1 + p_2 + p_3 - (p_1^2 + p_2^2 + p_3^2) = 0\\
& p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1
\end{align}
So that we have two defining equations,
\begin{align} \tag{4} \label{4}
& p_1^2 + p_2^2 + p_3^2 = 1\\
& p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1
\end{align}
According to the paper of Lifshitz & Khalatnikov:
Since the three numbers $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are connected by two relations, only one of them is independent. The numbers $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are never all equal,
and are equal in pairs only in the triplets of numbers $(0, 0, 1)$ and $(-1/3,2/3,2/3)$. In all the other cases they are distinct, one of them being negative and two
positive. We shall order them by,
\begin{equation} \tag{5} \label{5}
p_1 < p_2 < p_3
\end{equation}
so that $p_1, p_2, p_3$ lie in the intervals,
\begin{equation} \tag{6} \label{6}
-1/3 \leq p_1 \leq 0, \quad 0 \leq p_2 \leq 2/3, \quad 2/3 \leq p_3 \leq 1
\end{equation}
They may be represented in the parametric form,
\begin{equation} \tag{7} \label{7}
p_1 = \frac{-s}{1 + s + s^2}, \quad p_2 = \frac{s(1+s)}{1 + s + s^2}, \quad p_1 = \frac{1+s}{1 + s + s^2} 
\end{equation}
where the parameter $s$ runs from $0$ to $1$. The figure below shows the curves which
allow any two of the numbers $p_1, p_2, p_3$ to be determined from a given value
of the third (the three values lie on the same vertical).

Can anyone help explain how the parameterization eq.(\ref{7}) was derived? Lifshitz & Khalatnikov never expounded on how they found this, and I've also tried searching for other sources that may discuss this but I have not found anything.
